# redhat 6 version + xfs_repair or fsck.xfs in order to fix corrupted file-system

Tags: linux, redhat, hard-drive, xfs, fsck

we have redhat machines version - 6.x

all disks that mounted have xfs files system
as:

```
UUID=198s5364-a29c-429e-b16d-e772acd /data_SA              xfs     rw,noatime,inode64,allocsize=16m 1 2
```

we want to fix the file system on some of the disks,

what is the right approach to use

1. xfs_repair
2. fsck.xfs
3. fsck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best option is by **xfs_repair**

the steps are:

first find your device UUID in /dev/disk/by-uuid

find what is the disk that is related to the mount point folder

Example : According to the /etc/fstab the disk is **data_SA**

```
UUID=198s5364-a29c-429e-b16d-e772acd /data_SA              xfs     rw,noatime,inode64,allocsize=16m 1 2
```

Unmount the mount point folder

```
umount /data_SA ( or umount –l /data_SA  if it say busy )
```

Repair the file-system as the following:

```
xfs_repair /dev/disk/by-uuid/198s5364-a29c-429e-b16d-e772acd
```

Finally mount again the mount point folder

```
mount /data_SA
```

Answer (score 0):

From the fsck man page:

```
   fsck.xfs  is called by the generic Linux fsck(8) program at startup to check and repair an XFS filesystem.  XFS is a journaling filesystem and performs recovery at mount(8) time if
   necessary, so fsck.xfs simply exits with a zero exit status.

   If you wish to check the consistency of an XFS filesystem, or repair a damaged or corrupt XFS filesystem, see xfs_repair(8).
```

Comment: xfs_repair if you need to check/repair the filesystem, fsck.xfs dose nothing it just exits with 0 for compatibility

Comment: @shalom: "If you wish to check the consistency of an XFS filesystem, or repair a damaged or corrupt XFS filesystem, see xfs_repair(8)."